# Help understanding terms surrounding the Mishna Berura?

Tags: halacha, mishnah-berurah, chofetz-chaim

I was wondering if someone could help clarify the terms surrounding the Mishna Berura:

1. I know the Biur Halacha and Sha'ar Tzion were also written by the Chofetz Chaim ZT'L, but I was curious how they relate to each other, and why the Chofetz Chaim wrote them seperately from the MB?
2. What does it mean when it says "Menukad" on it? What does it mean when it's Oz v'Hadar Menukad, or just plain Menukad, or when it is Dirshu?

Comment: The only part that isn't a duplicate I think is about "Menukad" which is just the Hebrew word for "dotted" and means the text is presented with vowel marks. (from the same root as 'nekudos' or 'nikud'). Happy shopping!